# Match exact string from list of options

Tags: python, regex, python-re, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I am using pre-commit to run some hooks, and I have a regex where I only include a list of files (dirs) that I wish to run the hook on. The problem is that my regex matches exact string + any other appending string to the first string.

```
hooks:
- id: xdoc
  files: (?=(analytic|authentication|store))
  exclude: (?=(apps|serializers|admin|test|migrations|__init__.py))
  stages: [commit]
```

here I have initially two apps starting with the string `store`:

```
store
storespecifics
```

The above regex matches both, where I am only trying to match exact `store`.
I tried for example `(?=^(analytic|authentication|store)$)`, but nothing gets matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no need to involve positive lookaheads here as [pre-commit uses `re.search` to match paths](https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions) -- this is probably closer to what you want:

```yaml
        files: ^(analytic|authentication|store)/
        exclude: (apps|serializers|admin|test|migrations|__init__.py)
```

note that I use a `/` here to make sure we're at a folder boundary (matching `store/foo.py` but not `storespecifics/foo.py`)

I also anchor the match to the beginning with `^`, if that's not desirable you'd probably replace the `^` with a `/`

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: anchor the match to the beginning with ^ also didn't match any results at all, but replacing it with `/` did. Thank you!